# Rails Server won't start, Ignoring several gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was starting to work on some of my rails apps that I hadn't worked in a few weeks and despite my best efforts, I cannot get the rails server to run. This is happening with all my apps. Here is the error I keep getting.

```
Ignoring RedCloth-4.2.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine RedCloth --version 4.2.9
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.9
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.3.pre1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.3.pre1
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-4.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 4.0.5
Ignoring byebug-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.4.0
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.5
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring fast-stemmer-1.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine fast-stemmer --version 1.0.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.9
Ignoring ffi-1.9.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.8
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring json-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.5
Ignoring pg-0.18.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.18.2
Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.17.1
Ignoring posix-spawn-0.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine posix-spawn --version 0.3.11
Ignoring rdiscount-2.1.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rdiscount --version 2.1.7
Ignoring redcarpet-3.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.3.2
Ignoring redcarpet-3.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.2.1
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.10
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.9
Ignoring thin-1.5.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thin --version 1.5.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
Ignoring yajl-ruby-1.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine yajl-ruby --version 1.2.1
Ignoring RedCloth-4.2.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine RedCloth --version 4.2.9
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.9
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.3.pre1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.3.pre1
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-4.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 4.0.5
Ignoring byebug-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.4.0
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.5
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring fast-stemmer-1.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine fast-stemmer --version 1.0.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.9
Ignoring ffi-1.9.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.8
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring json-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.5
Ignoring pg-0.18.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.18.2
Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.17.1
Ignoring posix-spawn-0.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine posix-spawn --version 0.3.11
Ignoring rdiscount-2.1.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rdiscount --version 2.1.7
Ignoring redcarpet-3.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.3.2
Ignoring redcarpet-3.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.2.1
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.11
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.10
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.9
Ignoring thin-1.5.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine thin --version 1.5.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
Ignoring yajl-ruby-1.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine yajl-ruby --version 1.2.1
/Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/code/jehrni/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/code/jehrni/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/code/jehrni/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/danieluribe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/danieluribe/code/jehrni/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

The only things I can think of that I've done in the past few weeks is install Jekyll and play around with SQL. I'm having a hard time finding the SQL (I find derivative files) so I suspect I may have uninstalled it.

I tried bundle install and tried to update gems and curl with no luck. I considered imploding rvm but wasn't confident in that as I had an even worse crash after that happened. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the given step would help.

**1:** `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

**2:** `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`  # install `RVM (development version)`

**3:** `rvm get head` #  Make Sure RVM up to date

**4:** `rvm install ruby` # will install latest version of ruby

**5:** `rvm list` # Listing install rubies will you get versions of ruby which is installed by RVM

**6:**  `rvm use < ruby-version >` # for instances `ruby-1.9.3-p125`

**7:** `gem install rails`

Would work !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and running `gem pristine --all` in the terminal fixed the problem immediately and I was able to run `rails server`.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the problem after upgrading the ruby version for my Rails project, using rbenv. `gem pristine --all` didn't work for me, but deleting `vendor/bundle` (which is where I have project dependencies install for my Rails app) and running `bundle install` cleared it up for me:

```
$ rm -rf vendor/bundle
$ bundle install
```